# Array on ThisWorksheet isn't usable on Sheet1

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have an excel timesheet I'm customizing. I want to the populate the activity code in one column when I choose (from dropdown) the activity type in another column.

I'm using vba to assign the table of codes and types to an array and I've done this on ThisWorkbook. On the timesheet page (Sheet1), I've created code to actually match the type and input a value into the code column (I tested current date first as proof of concept). But when I went to match the array values (so I could assign the code), I'm getting type mismatch because the array doesn't exist on Sheet1 (but on ThisWorksheet).

I've tried making the Array value global, making a new array variable and assigning the original array to a secondary global array, both without success. I'm overlooking something, but i'm drawing a blank.

---

ThisWorkbook:

---

```
Option Explicit
Dim KeyArrTrans As Variant

Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim KeyArr As Variant

    With Sheets("Key")
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    'Debug.Print LastRow

    KeyArr = Sheets("Key").Range("A3:B" & LastRow).Value

    'WriteArrayToImmediateWindow KeyArr
    KeyArrTrans = KeyArr

    'Debug.Print KeyArr(1, 1)

End Sub

Sub WriteArrayToImmediateWindow(arrSubA As Variant)

    Dim rowString As String
    Dim iSubA As Long
    Dim jSubA As Long

    rowString = ""

    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print "The array is: "

    For iSubA = 1 To UBound(arrSubA, 1)
        rowString = arrSubA(iSubA, 1)
        For jSubA = 2 To UBound(arrSubA, 2)
            rowString = rowString & "," & arrSubA(iSubA, jSubA)
        Next jSubA
        Debug.Print rowString
    Next iSubA

End Sub
```

---

Sheet1:

---

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim tRowX As Integer
    Dim tColX As Integer
    Dim WorkPerfCol As Integer
    Dim ActivCol As Integer
    Dim WorkValue As String
    Dim curDate As Date
    Dim tArr As Integer
    Dim i As Long
    Dim KeyUBound As Integer

    WorkPerfCol = 3
    ActivCol = 2
    Debug.Print UBound(KeyArrTrans, 1)
    'KeyUBound = UBound(KeyArrTrans, 1)

    If Target.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Column = WorkPerfCol And Target.Row >= 29 And Target.Row <= 41 Then

            tColX = Target.Column
            tRowX = Target.Row
            WorkValue = Cells(tRowX, tColX).Value

            For i = 1 To KeyUBound
                If KeyArrTrans(i, 2) = WorkValue Then
                    Debug.Print KeyArrTrans(i, 2), KeyArrTrans(i, 1)
                    'ActiveSheet.Cells(tRowX,ActivCol.Value = KeyArrTrans(i,1))
                End If
            Next

            Debug.Print WorkValue, tColX, tRowX
            curDate = Date
            'ActiveSheet.Cells(tRowX, ActivCol).Value = curDate

        End If
    End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Dim` keyword declares a *local variable*. When used at module level, it declares a *private* variable with module scope, i.e. exactly the same thing as if it were declared with the `Private` keyword. For this reason, prefer using `Dim` for locals, and `Private` for module variables.

`ThisWorkbook` is a special kind of module - it's a *document module*, which is a *class* that *inherits* members from a base class - in this case the `Excel.Workbook` class. `ThisWorkbook` is also a global identifier, that refers to the *instance* of the `ThisWorkbook` class that is globally accessible within your VBA project.

Being a *class module*, any `Public` members can be accessed from outside that module, given an instance of the class. Since there's a global object variable named after that class, its `Public` members can be accessed with `ThisWorkbook.MemberName`.

So you can declare `KeyArrTrans` with the `Public` keyword, effectively making it global (i.e. effectively the same as declaring it public in a *standard module* and accessing it qualified with the module's name).

The problem this creates, is that now any code anywhere in the project is allowed to take that variable and *point it somewhere else*.

Most likely what you want/need isn't to be able to alter the actual array pointer from other modules, but merely access its contents. If you need to expose the array contents as read-only data, you'll need to write your own data structure ...and that is likely very much overkill.

So instead, you can *encapsulate* the array pointer and expose it as a *get-only property*, by keeping the declaration private (`Dim`/`Private`), and adding a `Public Property Get` member to `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Public Property Get AllTheKeys() As Variant
    AllTheKeys = KeyArrTrans
End Property
```

That way (i.e. without exposing a `Public Property Let` mutator), other code can read the array and write to its elements, but they can't assign to the array itself - and that protection is enforced by the compiler!

Now you can access the array through the `AllTheKeys` property exposed by `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Debug.Print UBound(ThisWorkbook.AllTheKeys, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`ThisWorkbook` is a class module. It represents an object. You cannot address a field declared on that object without specifying the name of the object.

So either declare `KeyArrTrans` with the `Public` keyword (instead of `Dim`) and address `KeyArrTrans` as `ThisWorkbook.KeyArrTrans`, or put the array into a plain module. Public variables declared in a plain module are globally accessible without specifying the name of the module.